# Qt for android doesn't find any compatible devices

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to write android applications with Qt5.2. My project builds without any error, but when i'm trying to RUN it says i don't have any compatible devices. I configured QT creator according to this [enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nkhlhBwkjk)
I don't know what's the problem. I will appreciate any help from you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Qt Creator: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11658

It is a changed behaviour in the latest version of the Android SDK that lists Virtual Devices with some prefix. So instead of armeabi-v7a it's returning default/armeabi-v7a, resulting in QtCreator complaining that the ABI is not supported.

You can overcome this problem by:

In QtCreator -> Projects -> BuildEnvironment add the variable

```
ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH=default/armeabi-v7a
```

Then the AVDs are shown as compatible.