# Qt for android doesn't find any compatible devices answer found but dont know how

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator

Well I am complete new to Qt and to make it simple and easy, this person had the same issue

[Qt for android doesn't find any compatible devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741737/qt-for-android-doesnt-find-any-compatible-devices)

They seem to fix it by someone saying

You can overcome this problem by:

> In QtCreator -> Projects -> BuildEnvironment add the variable
>
> ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH=default/armeabi-v7a

But when I click File, new and I dont see any of the options.

Comment: Which QtCreator version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in the post you mentioned is no longer required. You can download and install the newest version of Qt Creator (currently Qt Creator 3.1). This issue has been fixed in the recent version as you can see [Here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11658). So there is no need to make a build environment variable.

Comment: That's the current version of Qt. The current version of Qt Creator is 3.1. The binary packages for Qt 5.2.1 include Qt 5.2.1 libraries and Qt Creator 3.0.1. You can download Qt Creator 3.1 installer seperatly.

Comment: Thanks dude, can you help me on my other post